# PM2: Deploy multiple environments on a single server?

Tags: pm2

I am using PM2 for deployment / process management, and the application handles lots of DNS tasks, and so it's easiest if I run the development app from the remote server, and either Rsyncing or SFTPing on save (still sorting this out).

This being the case, it is the idea case for the dev app to be on the same VM as the production app. However, the structure of the PM2 deployment configuration file (`ecosystem.config.js`) doesn't seem to make this possible, as when I run `pm2 deploy development`, the development version overtakes the production process on the VM.

Here is what I have:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "APP NAME",
      script: "app.js",
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
        ...
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        ...
      }
    }
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "user",
      host: ["123.123.123.123"],
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: "git@gitlab.com:me/repo.git",
      path: "/var/www/app",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production"
    },
    development: {
      user: "user",
      host: ["123.123.123.123"],
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: "git@gitlab.com:me/repo.git",
      path: "/var/www/app-dev",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env development"
    }
  }
};
```

Any thoughts for the best way to go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Hello, did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 5):

After referencing this [PR](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/pull/2650), I'm thinking you should be able to add `append_env_to_name: true` as a property to the object in the `apps` array of the `ecosystem.config.js`:

So your updated `ecosystem.config.js` file would be as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "APP NAME",
      append_env_to_name: true // <===== add this line
      script: "app.js",
      env_development: {
        NODE_ENV: "development",
        ...
      },
      env_production: {
        NODE_ENV: "production",
        ...
      }
    }
  ],
  deploy: {
    production: {
      user: "user",
      host: ["123.123.123.123"],
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: "git@gitlab.com:me/repo.git",
      path: "/var/www/app",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production"
    },
    development: {
      user: "user",
      host: ["123.123.123.123"],
      ref: "origin/master",
      repo: "git@gitlab.com:me/repo.git",
      path: "/var/www/app-dev",
      "post-deploy":
        "npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env development"
    }
  }
};
```